# Link Product A and Product B to the same product with unique SKU and discret stock

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, sku

like my Title says we want to link a product A and B to the same product.
[image: A reduced image of my topic]

At this point, we aren't using at our Magento 2 shop a Configurable Product to select a specified product only to create Products.

At the ebay-side, we want to use a Configurable Product with only 2 Dropdowns which choosing implies the other attributes.

We want to keep stock so using 2 different articles wouldn't be great because of the overhead.